# To remove block in product page in magento 2

Tags: product, layout, frontend, magento2.2, review

I have created custom module for *product review*.If I click the review link, It shows the **popup**. In that it contains **Default review form** (But I have modified the form).In my layout file I have hided the **review tab** which is present in the product page in `calalog_product_view.xml`. But now, It shows following json error while loading the product page.

> Error

```
**Uncaught SyntaxError:** Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at run (layout.js:164)
    at app.js:14
    at main.js:31
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1650)
    at Module.check (require.js:866)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1113)
    at require.js:132
    at require.js:1156
    at each (require.js:57)
run @ layout.js:164
(anonymous) @ app.js:14
(anonymous) @ main.js:31
execCb @ require.js:1650
check @ require.js:866
(anonymous) @ require.js:1113
(anonymous) @ require.js:132
(anonymous) @ require.js:1156
each @ require.js:57
emit @ require.js:1155
check @ require.js:917
(anonymous) @ require.js:1113
(anonymous) @ require.js:132
(anonymous) @ require.js:1156
each @ require.js:57
emit @ require.js:1155
check @ require.js:917
enable @ require.js:1143
init @ require.js:774
(anonymous) @ require.js:991
(anonymous) @ require.js:132
(anonymous) @ mixins.js:106
execCb @ require.js:1650
check @ require.js:866
(anonymous) @ require.js:1113
(anonymous) @ require.js:132
(anonymous) @ require.js:1156
each @ require.js:57
emit @ require.js:1155
check @ require.js:917
enable @ require.js:1143
init @ require.js:774
callGetModule @ require.js:1170
completeLoad @ require.js:1544
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1671
```

Please provide the suggestion
My custom layout file

**calalog_product_view.xml**

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove= "true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.review">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">XXX_YYYY::review.phtml</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.review.popup" template="XXX_YYYY::popup.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="custom.product.review.form" as="custom.review_form" template="XXX_YYYY::form.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Replce This With Your Layout Code:

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab" remove= "true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.review">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">OX_ProductReview::review.phtml</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.review.popup" template="XXX_YYYY::popup.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Review\Block\Form" name="custom.product.review.form" as="custom.review_form" template="XXX_YYYY::form.phtml">
                    //New Added Container.
                    <container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

I've Also Faced That Js Error By Adding This:

```
<container name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Review Form Fields Before"/>
```

Js Error Will Remove After Adding This Container.. Js Error Is Resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your response, But still js error is showing

Comment: I have added the container as you said but error not resolved

Comment: same error or some other error..?

Comment: I got the same error